# Can't run Julia script using environment libraries

Tags: csv, dependencies, julia

Heyo.

I've been struggling running packages and might need some help. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Used *Pkg* to generate a project called *Void*
2. Added *CSV* and *DataFrames* as dependencies (which got listed in the TOML)
3. Saw the project status (which included both libraries)
4. Instantiated

But still, my project won't run anything that contains the libraries. Here's my code:

```
# src/Void.jl
using CSV, DataFrames

module Void
    function testing()
        frame = CSV.read("sheet.csv", DataFrame)
        print(frame)
    end
end

Void.testing()

export Void
```

I tried `julia --project=. src/Void.jl` to run this script, but it gave me `` UndefVarError: `CSV` not defined ``.

Trying `julia --project=.` and `using Void` in this order threw me an error saying CSV ain't a dependency too.

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Base does not have CSV in its dependencies:
- You may have a partially installed environment. Try `Pkg.instantiate()`
  to ensure all packages in the environment are installed.
- Or, if you have Base checked out for development and have
  added CSV as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
  environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
- Otherwise you may need to report an issue with Base
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ .\loading.jl:1634 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ .\lock.jl:267 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1611
 [4] include
   @ .\Base.jl:457 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt128}}, source::Nothing)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:2049
 [6] top-level scope
   @ stdin:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\alunotemp\Área de Trabalho\Codes\Void\src\Void.jl:1
in expression starting at stdin:3
```

I also tried doing what the error sugested, but none worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `using CSV, DataFrames` inside the module like this:

```
module Void
    using CSV, DataFrames
    function testing()
        frame = CSV.read("sheet.csv", DataFrame)
        print(frame)
    end
end
```

Note though that creating modules is not very simple as there are several concepts you need to learn. I recommend you read in detail https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/ before doing this.

Most Julia users never need to create their own modules.